# How to use "StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()" in Firebase?

Tags: ios, swift, firebase, firebase-storage

Hi I have Question about making ios Application wiht Firebase

Nowadays I am making a chat Application using watching an YouTube

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=MJ1r5jjdf4Q&index=4&list=PLmdU__e_zPf9uczwNhLNANvxT5mzxMiXQ

In here

At the Source code, `let imageUrl = data?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString` this got an error  "Value of type 'StorageMetadata' has no member 'downloadURL'"

I heard the downloadURL() was deprecated in Firebase So, docs said using `StorageReference.downloadURLWithCompletion()` instead of `downloadURL`.

But I don't know how to change the code.

Please tell me how to change the code. And chage the code

Thank you!

```
func signupEvent(){
    Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){(user,err) in
        let uid = user?.user.uid 
        let image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.1)

        Storage.storage().reference().child("userImage").child(uid!).putData(image!, metadata:nil, completion:{(data, error) in
            let imageUrl = data?.downloadURL()?.absoluteString
            Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).setValue(["name": self.name.text!, "profileImageUrl" : imageUrl])

        })

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can check the updated documentation of Firebase 5 upload files [here](https://firebase.google.com/docs/storage/ios/upload-files#upload_from_data_in_memory), the API changed so you should use StorageReference's downloadURL method.

So your code become something like this:

```
func signupEvent(){
  Auth.auth().createUser(withEmail: email.text!, password: password.text!){(user,err) in
    let uid = user?.user.uid 
    let image = UIImageJPEGRepresentation(self.imageView.image!, 0.1)

    let storageItem = Storage.storage().reference().child("userImage").child(uid!)
    storageItem.putData(image!, metadata:nil, completion:{(data, error) in
        // Now is good to check errors
        if error != nil {
            print("Error: couldn't upload the image")
        }
        else {
            storageItem.downloadURL(completion: { (url, error) in
                if error != nil {
                    print(error!)
                    return
                }
                if url != nil {
                    let imageUrl = url!.absoluteString
                    Database.database().reference().child("users").child(uid).setValue(["name": self.name.text!, "profileImageUrl" : imageUrl])
                }
            }
        }
    })

 }
}
```